# Create instance from within static method

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, static

In PHP it's `$instance = new static();`

How do you do this in nodejs ?

From a static method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` refers to class constructor inside static methods.

It's:

```
class Foo {
  static factory() {
    return new this();
  }
}

Foo.factory();
```